# SQL Server: retrieve 1 value from a duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have trouble retrieving max 1 value from each duplicate. It works fine when I don't have **Name** included in the query, but when I want name in, it retrieves duplicate rows, even when I'm using the MAX function.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT 
    b.Name, MAX(a.receiver), a.DATE1 = MIN(a.DATE1)
FROM 
    Table1 a
INNER JOIN
    Table2 b ON a.receiver = b.account
WHERE
    Company IN (1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY
    RECEIVER, b.name
```

Result:

```
    NAME      |  Receiver  |  DATE1
    Apple     |   12345    |  2018-01-18 
    Apple A/S |   12345    |  2018-01-19 
    GDG       |   54544    |  2018-01-20 
    BNS       |   54455    |  2018-01-23
```

Expected result:

```
    NAME      |  Receiver  |  DATE1
    Apple     |   12345    |  2018-01-18 
    GDG       |   54544    |  2018-01-20 
    BNS       |   54455    |  2018-01-23
```

Comment: Is there any reason Apple and Apple A/S needs to be considered as same name?

Comment: Yes, sometimes different users from the same company input different info when submitting for example a form.

Comment: then that is data cleaning issue (long sustained way); for now you can handle easiest way via CASE statement

Comment: Select name = case when b.name like '%apple%' then 'apple' else b.name end ...and rest of your col.

Comment: Have a look at your data. It doesn't make sense that there are two different names for the same account

Comment: Apple and Apple A/S may be the same company, but "Apple Pie Inc." would not.  If you can't standardize the user input via a drop-down or combo box, then you may really need a mapping table.

Comment: ***You*** need to tell us the business logic you want to implement so that `'Apple A/S'` is mapped to `'Apple'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't seem to care which name is chosen, just place an aggregate on that column.

It doesn't make sense that the same receiver ID can have different names though. Looks like you aren't using keys or constraints at all here...

```
SELECT 
    min(b.name),
    a.receiver, 
    DATE1 = min(a.DATE1),
FROM Table1 a
Inner join Table2 b
on a.receiver = b.account
WHERE
Company in (1,2,3,4,5)
group by RECEIVER
```

Comment: Thanks! this is perfect

Comment: As good a guess as any until they clarify what they actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate the name, do not group by it. For example, `MIN(name)` will show 'Appple' and `MAX(name)` will show 'Apple A/S'.

On other hand `a.DATE1 = min(a.DATE1)` is a wrong expression in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT MIN(b.Name), MAX(a.receiver), min(a.DATE1) AS DATE1
FROM Table1 a
Inner join Table2 b
on a.receiver = b.account
WHERE
Company in (1,2,3,4,5)
group by RECEIVER
```